# Edit this task x-header issue in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, sharepoint, exchange-2003

I have found out the following regarding an issue I am having with an Edit This Task button for Sharepoint in Outlook 2007.

You will need to check with your Exchange Server administrator and make sure the following X-Headers are not being stripped or blocked.

```
X-Sharing-WSSBaseUrl
X-AlertWebSoap
X-Sharing-ItemID
X-Sharing-Remote-Uid
X-Sharing-Config-Url
X-AlertServerType
X-AlertWebUrl
X-AlertId
X-AlertTitle
X-Sharing-Title
```

I have looked at http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2004/08/using-x-headers-with-exchange.html and it makes no sense to me.

I don't know how to check this out, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing off as there does not appear to be an answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason Exchange would remove headers by itself, so I'll offer some quick suggestions that might give you some inspiration.

- Have you got any hardware devices (firewalls, antivirus scanners, spam filters etc) in front of the Exchange server? It's possible these might remove headers from messages.
- It could be possible for an SMTP sink to remove headers. Run `smtpreg.vbs /enum` on the Exchange 2003 server to see if you have any event sinks registered. If you do, examine them and see what they do.

Failing that, if you explain the actual issue you're having with Sharepoint, we might be able to offer a solution based on that instead (the email headers might be a total red herring).

Comment: Ben, thanks for your reply.

The issue we are having is that we have a workflow solution in place and when we get an email there is an button in the email to "Edit This Task", when it's clicked Outlook hangs and an egg timer remains up until it eventuallly times out.

We have Spam Filter in place however as this is internal the mail's should not go through the spam filter.

I tried runnig smtpreg.vbs /enum on the Exchange 2003 server and it came up with a ton of windows script host errors which I didn't know what was important and what wasn't.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is an answer to this sadly